# Ruby on Rails : symbol as argument in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I understand what is passed to the `form_for` method when doing something like :

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %> ... <% end %>
```

if `@user` is set in the controller. This is pretty obvious.

But what happens when we pass `:user`, as I have seen in many examples ?

```
<% form_for(:user) do |f| %> ... <% end %>
```

When should I use the symbol version ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [instance variable vs. symbol in ruby on rails (form\_for)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the symbol will generate:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
```

Using the object @user set to new you get:

```
<form action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
```

If you set @user to something else it will change the form tag generated, of course
... try it out for yourself.

In the end it all depends what you're trying to do. You might want to use the symbol if you have multiple :user forms on the same page.

Comment: I did give this a test but the value for action doesn't change (it remains `/users`). Although, I get the same thing as you mentioned in the code block for the class and id.