# Do I use camelCase to reference a rails model that is two words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called AlphaUser. When I create a form for it, do I camelCase the symbol?

```
<%= form_for :alphaUser
```

or

```
<%= form_for :alpha_user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use camel case, especially when using a symbol (e.g. :alphaUser).

If your model is AlphaUser, you'll either want to use:

```
<%= form_for AlphaUser.new %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for :alpha_user %>
```

These two approaches behave differently, so it kind of depends on what you want to do...  See this post for more info on the difference: [Ruby on Rails : symbol as argument in form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for)

Or better yet instantiate the new object in your controller (e.g. @alpha_user = AlphaUser.new) and use that in your form_for, e.g.

```
<%= form_form @alpha_user %>
```