# Why symbol instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to break apart Rails code more so I can understand what's happening

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This code is from 5.2 section of edgeguides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

```
 <%= form_for :article do |f| %>
```

That line is bothering me. Why is it a symbol instead of @article?

@article would be an instance of Article object, right? And wouldn't you want that for form_for?

ps. feel free to edit the title to be more reflective of this post.

**EDIT** ... I understand why this post is marked as duplicate, and I'm fine with letting that stand as.

However, I just had to post this. I don't know if this is me (ie, my error) or the fact that I'm dealing with Rails 4, but when I changed it from a symbol (:article) to object (@article) - I got this error when I refreshed the new page.

This is the error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Just for clarification, this is the line I changed:

```
 <%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

No, not trying to change the question, or any of that. I had assumed initially when I wrote up this post, that either would work. But just for the heck of it, after reading the responses, I tried the @, and got that error.

So, wondering what's going on, or if it's just me?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for

Comment: +1 This is a valid question and I can tell it's an earnest attempt in trying to understand Rails.  It will probably get marked as a dup by the mods, however.  Good job in thinking critically about your code and not just blinding following conventions.

Comment: form_for needs to know two things: the 'name' to use for the object (gets converted into the first part of field names) and the object itself. If you pass a symbol, the helper will attempt to find the actual object in an instance variable of the same name. More info in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: @Powers those answers are out of date

Comment: Hey, all, sorry for taking so long in responding back. Had to go somewhere, and then when I came back to this ... had to process all the comments and answer a bit. Still a tad confused.

Comment: @Powers, hey, appreciate the duplicate links. They sorta make it clear to me that :article means that it would get a particular action, ie `form action="/posts"` and @article would result in this: `form action="/posts/create"`. But I am puzzled that in my case, when I tried @article, I got an error. It's mentioned in my edit in above post.

Comment: @Matt Jones, appreciate the link. Actually found it interesting to read it. Also your comment was informative. Didn't realize that the helper would attempt to find the actual object. Tried just doing `@article`, and got a weird error. It's clarified further in my edit. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suspicion is correct, but you did not read far enough:

> When you call form_for, you pass it an identifying object for this
>   form. In this case, it's the symbol :article. This tells the form_for
>   helper what this form is for. Inside the block for this method, the
>   FormBuilder object - represented by f - is used to build two labels
>   and two text fields, one each for the title and text of an article.
>   Finally, a call to submit on the f object will create a submit button
>   for the form.
>
> There's one problem with this form though. If you inspect the HTML
>   that is generated, by viewing the source of the page, you will see
>   that the action attribute for the form is pointing at /articles/new.
>   This is a problem because this route goes to the very page that you're
>   on right at the moment, and that route should only be used to display
>   the form for a new article.
>
> The form needs to use a different URL in order to go somewhere else.
>   This can be done quite simply with the :url option of form_for.
>   Typically in Rails, the action that is used for new form submissions
>   like this is called "create", and so the form should be pointed to
>   that action.

TLDR

use `form_for(@article || Article.new) do |f|`

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Ok, read your paragraph above which as you mention is from guides link. What I don't get is how does it tell the form_for helper what this form is for. I mean, don't you need the attributes from the object? And symbols pass that?

Comment: and also, tried your line. It works, btw. So thank you for giving me a different way of trying it out. What I'm trying to understand now is this `||`. Is that a OR operator? So, what your line is in essence is saying to form_for is either use @article object, or build a new Article object and then loop it, right?

Comment: but also (sorry for so many comments!), please see my edit in post above. My understanding is that they're supposed to be interchangeable symbol vs object (yeah, I get it, different form action), and they don't seem to be when I try to put symbol instead. Any ideas why?

Comment: ,ugh, just realized after reading MattJones comment and commenting back, that my first comment is invalid because the form_for looks for the object, if the symbol is used, right? That's how the attributes are passed, right?