# Rails correct way to submit nested parameters in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This code successfully creates a new Notice, as intended:

In the submit form:

```
<%= form_tag( {controller: "notices", action: "create"}, method: "post", class: "comment_form", html: { multipart: true } ) do %>
  .
  <%= hidden_field_tag "notice[supernotice][commentee_id]", notice.id %>
  .
<% end %>
```

In the notices_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @notice = @character.notices.build(notice_params)
  if @notice.save
    if !params[:notice][:supernotice][:commentee_id].nil?
      @notice.create_comment(params[:notice][:supernotice][:commentee_id]) # hits the create_comment method in notice.rb
    end
  end

def notice_params
  params.require(:notice).permit(:content, :picture, :latitude, :longitude, supernotice_attributes: [:commentee_id] )
end
```

Class notice.rb:

```
has_one :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :supernotice

def create_comment(other_notice_id)
  create_active_comment_relationship(commentee_id: other_notice_id)
end
```

However, the logs show the error: `Unpermitted parameter: supernotice`. How do I get rid of this error? What is wrong with the way I am submitting the nested parameter?

Comment: Try changing permit from `supernotice_attributes` to `supernotices_attributes`.  Also, you should be accessing `notice_params` in your controller and avoid using `params` directly.

Comment: Using `supernotices_attributes` makes no difference sadly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "notice[supernotice_attributes][0][commentee_id]", notice.id %>
```

But in general, the way you create your nested attributes is wrong. You should start with the form_for helper, and then for nested attributes use f.fields_for helper. For example:

```
<%= form_for @notice do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :supernotice do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.hidden_field :commentee_id, @notice.id %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

One more thing. If you create your form in the way I proposed, most likely you will not need that hidden field at all because rails will take care of it. Meaning, during creation rails will know what id to populate on commentee_id.

Comment: What's wrong with using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`? Why does `form_tag` exist if it's wrong?

Comment: @Bazley, form_tag is just more difficult to work with. I think form_tag is more appropriate for specific custom cases. But when you work with models and especially with nested attributes it is easier to use form_for and fields_for. Your case is a good example. If you rewrite the code with fields_for then you don't need that hidden field at all.

Comment: What's stopping me is that you need an instance variable for form_for. I don't want to use an instance variable. Can form_for be used without an instance variable?

Comment: Yes, you can use symbol instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for

Comment: Besides, according to your example you do have the variable "notice" from which you set the id. It might not be the one that you want to use in form_for, though.