# RoR: form_for :symbol vs @object do the odd way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I'm following the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial.

When generate the `view` for `create new article` `controller`, i use:
**Case 1**: `:article`

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
```

[image]
and get the error `No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"`
I thought that it should be `[POST] "/articles`
**Case 2** I change to: `@artical`

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

[image]
and it's OK.
Note that in **case 1**, the `submit button`'s text is: `Save article`, and that is `Create article` in **case 2**
It does the opposite way with [This SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006357/2810231).
It's too ambiguous to me!!! So could somebody help to me to explain it?
This is my [source code on github](https://github.com/CQBinh/demo-rails-blog)

Comment: Can you explain this **It does the opposite way**?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/957266/2483313 might be helpfull.

Comment: @Pavan: When i use :symbol, it's generate: `"/articles/new"` path, not `/articles` like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for/2006357#2006357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

This is how Rails work, so basically, you should pass an object to `form_for`.

### Long answer

After looking around the source code, here what is happening.
When you pass an object to `form_for`, the `action` will be computed with:

```
url_for(polymorphic_path(@object))
```

which will give `/articles` if the object is an article not persisted, or `/articles/:id` if the object is a persisted article.

When you pass a string or a symbol, the `action` results in `url_for` called
with an empty hash, resulting in the current path, in your case `/articles/new`. Note that if you show the form from, let's say `/articles/custom`, the path will be `/articles/custom`.

For the button, if you pass an object, the submit input value will be either
`I18n.t('helpers.submit.create')` or `I18n.t('helpers.submit.update')` depending on either your model is persisted or not. However, if you pass a string or a symbol, the value will be `I18n.t('helpers.submit.submit')`.

Here are the relevant line of codes from Rails source.

```
# actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L422
def form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
    # .....
    when String, Symbol
      object_name = record
      object      = nil
    else
      object      = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
      raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object
      object_name = options[:as] || model_name_from_record_or_class(object).param_key
      apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options)
    end
    # .....
    html_options = html_options_for_form(options[:url] || {}, html_options)
    form_tag_with_body(html_options, output)
  end

# actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L451
def apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options) #:nodoc:
    # ....
    options[:url] ||= if options.key?(:format)
                        polymorphic_path(record, format: options.delete(:format))
                      else
                        polymorphic_path(record, {})
                      end
  end

# actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L840
def html_options_for_form(url_for_options, options)
  options.stringify_keys.tap do |html_options|
    # ....
    html_options["action"]  = url_for(url_for_options)
    # ....
  end
end

# actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1873
def submit_default_value
  object = convert_to_model(@object)
  key    = object ? (object.persisted? ? :update : :create) : :submit
  # .....

  defaults = []
  defaults << :"helpers.submit.#{object_name}.#{key}"
  defaults << :"helpers.submit.#{key}"
  defaults << "#{key.to_s.humanize} #{model}"

  I18n.t(defaults.shift, model: model, default: defaults)
end

# locale/en.yml#L142
helpers:
  select:
    prompt: Please select
  submit:
    create: Create %{model}
    submit: Save %{model}
    update: Update %{model}
```

For the action, you can see that `apply_form_for_options!` is not called when you pass a string, so `options[:url]` remains `nil` if it was. When you pass an object, `apply_form_for_options!` set `options[:url]` to `polymorphic_path(@object)` if it was not set. This is then passed to `html_options_for_form`, where the `action` is set applying `url_for` to the value.

For the submit value, you can see how the key is taken depending on whether the form target is an object or not, and then translated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Howere, why does [RoR](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form) guided me to use the `:symbol`?

Comment: It explains just below that you should add the `url` option for it to work. I suppose it is to keep things simple and not confuse new users with Rails "magic".

Answer (score 1):

`form_for :article` created a form, but default url to submit is  `/articles/new`

action `new` of articles used to display the form to submit, not handle creating a new article

=> `resources :articles` will map it with `GET` method

you can specified an url for that form, or change the request method (not recommended)

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```