# Render simple_form from partial view on application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to create a partial view for my registration form and add it to the application layout file because it will be shown in the navigation bar in a dropdown menu.

How can I create this form in a partial view using `simple_form gem` and render it on `application.html.erb`?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: account_register_path) do |f| %>
```

Considering that the code above is the way to create the form and I don't know where I should define `@user` to be used in the application layout nor if I really need it.

Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put it in a partial, just have the `registration` view on its own, called with `render`...

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render "accounts/new" %>

#app/views/accounts/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for :user, url: account_register_path do |f| %>
...
```

Whilst [you can use a symbol to populate `form_for`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for), it won't include the attributes of the model, or the various hidden methods which give context (such as `id` etc).

---

If you wanted to populate the `accounts#new` view/action with a variable, you'll have to set it in your `ApplicationController`:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_user

   private

   def set_user
      @user = User.new
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
#app/views/accounts/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: account_register_path do |f| %>
```

--

The best way to implement this would be with Ajax -- this way, the `@user` object is only created when you need it (resolves bloat).

We've [done this before](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com):

[image]

You'd just need the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= link_to "New User", account_register_path, remote: true %>

#app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def new
      @user = User.new
      respond_with @user
   end 
end

#app/views/accounts/new.js.erb
$("<%=j render 'accounts/new' %>").appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I put it in a partial? I'm not using dynamic JS files in my project. I'm already using a template that I've bought from ThemeForest and has a bunch of JS files, so if I start adding dynamic JS files too it will become a complete mess IMHO.

Comment: It's not the partial, it's just you could get the same functionality by referencing a file you've already got

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand "referencing a file you've already got"

Comment: If you have an `accounts/new.html.erb` file, why not just reference that instead of creating a totally new partial?

Comment: But in this case I'd need to disable the layout for this action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define @user in the corresponding controller action (I would assume from your code, that controller is called account and action is register), it would be something like:

```
@user = User.new
```

In order to initialize instance being created/updated. Then, attributes used in all fields should match users database table.

Comment: If I do `@user = User.new` from `Account#Register` and render the partial that contains `<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: account_register_path) do |f| %>`, I get: `undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass`. So I had to change `@user` to `User.new` on simple_form helper to make it work. Is it possible to do in a different way?

Comment: That's weird. When rendering the register view, are you passing @user variable? Because render would just display view with the variables defined in that precise moment. Would you please show me how are you rendering in your controller?

Comment: I'm using just `render 'account/register_form'`. How should I initialize and pass the `@user` variable? From each controller?