# passing a symbol/instance variable to form_for doesn't generate the intended action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006357/7159163) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957266/7159163) both claim that the difference between passing a symbol into form_for, that is,
`<% form_for :post do |f| %>`  and
`<% form_for @post do |f| %>`

One difference is that `action = /posts/create` but I found something different, actually `action=/posts` instead of what was claimed.

When you pass a instance you get

`<form class="new_form" id="new_form" action="/forms"`

But when you pass a symbol you get

`<form action="/forms"`

(for both html versions I omitted charset and hidden etc)

So what's going on

Comment: Dude. Check the year on those questions.

Comment: So it's version related then?

Comment: 2010 was a loong time ago and the answer is no longer correct. Rails will never generate /posts/create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `<% form_for :post do |f| %>` and `<% form_for @post do |f| %>` is that the latter [binds the form to a model instance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

The latter will actually "hold" the values the user types in after submission. `form_for :post` just uses polymorphic routing the get the route and nests the inputs under the key `:post`.

Both generate the action `/posts` (for a new record) unless you really messed up the routes. `form_for @post` will generate a route to `/posts/:id` and change the method to patch if the record is `#persisted?`.

These are the [conventional routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) created by resources:

```
GET          /posts               posts#index
GET          /posts/:id           posts#show
GET          /posts/new           posts#new
POST         /posts               posts#create
GET          /posts/:id/edit      posts#edit
PATCH|PUT    /posts/:id           posts#update
DELETE       /posts/:id           posts#destroy
```

`/posts/create` is not a conventional route and will never be generated unless you define the route manually.

Comment: Rails 5 has a new `form_with` method that replaces `form_for` and `form_tag` with a single method with a more coherent signature.

Comment: So in the situation that im using a form to create a record e.g im making a new post should I use :post or @post? and why?

Comment: @post since it will bind the inputs to the params. Otherwise the form will be blank after an unsuccessful submission. It also lets you reuse the form as a partial. Run the scaffold generator for an example of this. rails g scaffold post