# Routes error when trying to update a database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this database about movies. I have made a `resources :movies` entry into my routes file for it, which should give it every route needed.

This is my movies controller: https://github.com/Veske/form/blob/ryhm/app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

And this is the error I get when I try to edit a movie on whatever.com/movies/1/edit:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/movies/1/edit"
```

These are the routes for movies right now:

```
movies_path  GET     /movies(.:format)   movies#index
POST     /movies(.:format)   movies#create
new_movie_path   GET     /movies/new(.:format)   movies#new
edit_movie_path  GET     /movies/:id/edit(.:format)  movies#edit
movie_path   GET     /movies/:id(.:format)   movies#show
PATCH    /movies/:id(.:format)   movies#update
PUT  /movies/:id(.:format)   movies#update
DELETE   /movies/:id(.:format)   movies#destroy
```

Now it is clearly seen that there is indeed no POST for movies/:id/edit right now. But why is that? Shouldnt the line I entered to routes give it to me?

EDIT:

Link to movies view: https://github.com/Veske/form/blob/ryhm/app/views/movies/edit.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling a POST on the form on the edit page, thus why you're getting the error `No route matches [POST] "/movies/1/edit"`.

Without seeing your code, this is just a guess, but either:

1. The form will need to be changed to use the PUT method.
2. The link to get to the edit for is bad, and needs to be a GET request.

Comment: Allright I made the form use PUT: <%= form_for :movie, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f| %>
But this does not change the fact that I have no put route for movies/:id/edit. How can I get that route? I mean...   the resources thing should do it for me?

Comment: In your controller, on the edit action, load up the movie in an instance variable (e.g. `@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])`) then do `form_for @movie`

Comment: Used the solution the other person suggested, but with both solutions the missing route problem persists. Any idea why is that?

Comment: There's something within your views trying to generate a generic form to `movie`, because forms default to a POST.

Comment: Posting link to my view in my original post so you could see. I dont think it is wrong what I have done there, I use the same thing when editing a user's info, and it works.

Comment: Using `form_for` with a symbol always produces a POST.  See this SO answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for

Answer (score 1):

Your `MoviesController` needs to set the movie in the edit action

```
def edit
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

Or better yet, DRY out your code and create a `before_action` that will set it for you for your restful routes

```
before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_movie
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: rake routes does still not show a PUT route for movies/1/edit then.

Comment: Tried the other version also but for some reason it still does not want to make a route for it..

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the method on the form as Rails will take care of that automatically.  What is checked into your repo right now for movies/edit.html.erb should work

Comment: Yes but when I get rid of it in the form, it tries to POST it again not PUT. But I guess the main problem is that the routes are not there which i need.

Comment: The routes look ok.  Does the error happen when you navigate to the edit page or when you actually try to submit it?

Comment: It happens when I actually try to submit it. Navigating to page is perfectly ok. I use a <%= link_to "Edit movie", edit_movie_path, class: "black" %> to navigate to it. It then automatically redirects me to the url of the movie I want to edit.