# What's the difference between @post and :post in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables, form-for

I've tried reading through the form_for Ruby doc, but it's still hard understanding the difference.

When loading the new.html.erb view, `:post` works, while `@post` does not. Here's the relevant view and controller:

```
This is Post's new.html.erb
<%= form_for(:post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :note, value: "Say something" %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

PostController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build
        puts "This is #{@post.user_id} user"
        redirect_to posts_path if @post.save #post/index.html.erb
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def signed_in_user
        redirect_to signout_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you try guides.rubyonrails.org?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:post` will get translated by Rails to "make me a new Post object and build form with it".
To use `@post` you first need to initialise it in controller action, i.e.

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

You should rather use `@post` because often you will end up wanting to do some initialisation before rendering a form (setting values, building associated objects, etc)

If you want to associate Post with User (using current_user) you can do it multiple ways:

1. @post.user_id = current_user.id
2. @post.user = current_user
3. @post = current_user.posts.build(params...)

Actually, third method is best way to do that.

Also, always remember to associate created objects with current_user in create/update action, so AFTER user sent the form. Putting user_id as form field will obviously allow user to change it!

Comment: As a follow-up question, how can I set the foreign_key of `@post`to `user_id`? Would it be `@post.user_id = current_user.id`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Remember to do it only in create action, so user can't tamper with value. See my updated answer.