# Why does my form_for :blog point to /blogs/new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I was going through [instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for?lq=1) SO post.

As per the most voted answer

> if you use symbol :post it creates

```
<form action="/posts" method="post">
```

> if you use the instance @post
>
> for @post = Post.new you will get

```
<form action="/posts/create" class="new_account" id="new_account" method="post">
```

But when I look at my rendered html page

```
<form action="/blogs/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" 
......
```

for the

**new.html.erb**

```
<%=form_for :blog do |f|%>
<%= f.text_field :title%>
<%= f.text_field :content%>
<%= f.submit :button %>
<% end %>
```

this throws me error saying

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/blogs/new"
```

Why is path mismatch occuring?

Comment: That's odd. What do you have in your routes.rb file for blogs?

Comment: @acsmith resources :blogs

Comment: Try putting the same code in `show.html.erb` and seeing what comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

action url of `form_for :blog` will be the url render that form

action url of `form_for "blog` based on paths of that object (defined in routes) combine with state of that object

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

> When the model is
>   represented by a string or symbol, as in the example above, if the
>   :url option is not specified, by default the form will be sent back to
>   the current url

Comment: that link contains everything :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer you have linked is relatively old and I am fairly sure not accurate anymore.

The Rails way to do it is using instance variable.

You should then use `<%= form_for @Blog.new do |f| =>`. This should render as

```
<form action="/blogs" method="post">
```

Comment: Yes, When I use instance variable it works fine. I was just trying to see what happens when I use symbol.

Comment: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for reference, but nowhere it states that you should use symbols

Answer (score 1):

For a resource, your form should be general for both `show.html.erb` and `new.html.erb`. In this instance, you should break your form into a partial `_form.html.erb`, and replace `:blog` with an instance variable:

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @blog do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :title%>
  <%= f.text_field :content%>
  <%= f.submit :button %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller actions should create this instance variable:

#### BlogsController

```
def new
  @blog = Blog.new
end

def update
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
end
```

And, finally, your templates should just call the partial

#### new.html.erb

```
render partial: :form
```

#### update.html.erb

```
render partial: :form
```